# Batch execute CREATE statements in Cypher / Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j / Cypher: I have a file that contains about 80,000 statements like this one:

> create (n:contract {numctr:"35129",CDETYPCTR:"GENERAL",DATDBTCTR:"455407200000",DATTFINCTR:"455407200000"});

I want to import them in my local neo4j server; when I drag the file to the "Drop a file to import Cypher or Grass" area in the neo4j admin, I get a silent failure (nothing is imported, I can't find an error message).

Is there a better way to execute all the statements in my file, like one would do in mysql:

mysql -u username -p database_name < file-to-import.sql

Thanks

Yann

Answer (score 3):

It's almost the same in Neo4j, if you have semicolon separated statements.

It also helps if you put a `BEGIN` at the beginning and a `COMMIT` at the end of your 80k statements so that they are all executed in one transaction.

```
bin/neo4j-shell -file file-to-import.cql
```

The shell connects to a running server, if you want to create a new datastore you can provide `-path path/to/graph.db`

Comment: I'm getting this in Windows when I try to run the neo4jshell: C:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\bin>Neo4jShell.bat
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/shell/Start
Client
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.shell.StartClient
...
Could not find the main class: org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.  Program will exit.